# Magento list - User search terms ( current user )

Tags: magento, search

I would like to list the search terms used by the current user.

Also the categories that the user already entered.

Comment: What you really want to do is:
Log search terms by User (in DB). [ I know logging of terms exists, but its not by user, if memory serves]
Log specific page views by user [that are category pages] (in DB).

Later: Ability to create a report with above information.
Possibly in one of the current Magento Admin Pages.

Comment: I got a layout now with that content to make. And I also saw some pages with that too, so I though it was already possible by Magento. So I will create this log :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So has been mentioned in the comments section magento logs search queries but not by user.

To log the user's visits to a category you could observe the following event:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent(
    'catalog_controller_category_init_after',
        array(
            'category' => $category,
            'controller_action' => $this
        )
    );
```

To log the user's searches then I would suggest observing the event:

```
catalogsearch_query_save_after
```